# When send an email, I receive multiple other empty emails with it in Java

Tags: java, email

I have a functionality that sends an email to me when an error occurs in the application. The problem is when it's triggered, I receive the right email with the subject and so on but I receive from `7` to `10` other empty emails on the same time.

Here is my code :

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        // Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                    to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject(subject);

            // Send the actual HTML message
            message.setContent(content, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {

            new PresenterException(mex.getMessage());
        }
```

How I call this method :

```
public void sendEmailError()
{
    String text = "blablablablaba";
    sendEmail(text);\\method above
}
```

Comment: What is the trigger of this code? Is it possible you're getting an email for each "step" in the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I suppose that is the trigger of this code who is doing that. If you have empty emails, maybe your "subject" and "content" are local variables, and the rest is instance variables. this could explain this strange behavior

Comment: Did you try adding prints (sysout) wherever you call sendEmailError? Not in sendEmailError iteself, but wherever you call this method. This will tell you if you're calling it more than once.